# what became of patent us240287?

Tags: us2402871

US240287 is listed as my Father William Atley Jenkins being on the patent. Would like to be able to research it more. Hope you can help me! Betty Monday

Comment: When I search that patent number I get a different inventor. Can you check it? https://patents.google.com/patent/US240287A/en

Comment: Maybe this patent? https://patents.google.com/patent/US2402871A/en?assignee=William+Atley+Jenkins

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean [US2402871](https://patents.google.com/patent/US2402871A/en). Your father, William Atley Jenkins is listed as the original assignee. The inventor is William Madison Butler. The assignee is the "owner" of the patent and is the person or company that can monetize it. Looking at the actual patent, we see the following:
[image]

It would seem the Mr. Butler valued your fathers contributions enough to award him one third the value of the patent. The patent was granted in June 25, 1946 and would have expired 17 years later (which is how patent terms worked prior to 1995).

It seems to be a device for vaporizing a liquid for use in domestic applications requiring burning of the gas (perhaps a stove or home heating). It was cited by only a single other [patent application](https://patents.google.com/patent/FR2850736A1/en) which is listed as withdrawn. This suggests in was not a very important patent. There is no way for me to determine if a commercial device was ever sold based on this patent or whether it was a commercial success outside of normal web searching techniques which you can do for yourself.

Comment: My Father actually worked for Mr. Butler so it is confusing to me to understand how the patent came about. My Father's job was called a gas plumber. He was the actual hands on person while Mr. Butler owned the company. That is why I was confused over Mr. Butler being the inventor.

Comment: @bettymonday  Looking at the actual patent, it say "assignor of one third to William Atley Jenkins". It looks like his boss rewarded your dad with one third the value of the patent.

Comment: @bettymonday  I edited the answer to add the divided assignment. If you find the answer acceptable, it would be nice if you could accept it by clicking on the check mark.